# Gear S3 is failing to discover nearby devices via bluetooth

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

My goal is to discover nearby devices via bluetooth. According to documentation: https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/connectivity-and-wireless/bluetooth I'm running this code in my Gear S3 device:

```
var adapter = tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter();

var discoverDevicesSuccessCallback = {
    ondevicefound: function(device) {
        alert('Found device - name: ' + device.name);
    }
};

/* Discover devices */
adapter.discoverDevices(discoverDevicesSuccessCallback, null);
```

And I added these privileges:

```
http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth
http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth.gap
http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth.admin
```

I set some devices as discoverable and I checked that problem is not related to them.

What am I doing wrong? What are the possible solutions?

Comment: Did you add the privileges ?

Comment: @Iqbalhossain - Sure, I added them

Comment: share API version of your app, OS version of your device also

Comment: @Iqbalhossain - my API version is 4.0 and OS version of my device is 3.0. But when I changed API version to 3.0 nothing happened

Comment: Privilege bluetooth.gap was required for 2.3.2 and lower versions...you may use only bluetooth

Comment: I found the solution. @Iqbalhossain - Thank you for replying me anyway ))

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem. In your tizen-studio IDE go to **config.xml -> Tizen** tab and change "**Required version**" to **3.0**

[image]